# How to execute a script based on a file

Tags: shell, files, for, oracle-database

I am trying to write a script that will connect to Oracle from a jump server (i.e) I will execute my script from a jump server, In my script I will have a config file as below

```
#USERNAME   PASSWORD    TNSNAMES    SUCCESS/FAIL
ODB        ODB123       ODB1        
CDC        CDC123       CDC1
```

So , Now i will pass the config file in a loop and will execute

```
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -S ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@${TNSNAMES}
```

So by executing the above query for the first time in a loop. It should try logging into the server using the above username and password and it should write into the `config` file like `PASS` if the connection succeeded and `FAIL` if connection failed.

```
#USERNAME   PASSWORD    TNSNAMES    SUCCESS/FAIL
ODB         ODB123      ODB1        PASS
CDC         CDC123      CDC1        FAIL
```

And again it should read the updated `config` file and if it is PASS it should get into the database and do respective sqls we call. And it should ignore the database if `FAIL`.

I have tried the below script which will write the contents to other file.

```
#!/bin/sh

. ~/.ODBenv
cat test.txt | grep '^#' > test1.txt
cat test.txt | grep -v '^#' | awk 'NF'|while read i;do
#if [ -z "$i" ]
#then
#break;
#fi
user_name=`echo $i|awk {'print $1'}`
password=`echo $i|awk {'print $2'}`
TNS_NAME=`echo $i|awk {'print $3'}`
echo "exit" | ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -S  ${user_name}/${password}@${TNS_NAME} |grep -E 'ORA|SP2' > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo -e "${user_name}\t      ${password}\t   ${TNS_NAME}\t   PASS">>test1.txt
else
   echo -e "${user_name}\t      ${password}\t   ${TNS_NAME}\t   FAIL">>test1.txt
fi
done
#done < test.txt|grep -v "^#" | awk "NF"
```

I tried writing the same contents into a new file and the above script worked.

Any idea how to write in the Original file like PASS/FAIL. Original file is as mentioned below.

```
#USERNAME   PASSWORD    TNSNAMES    SUCCESS/FAIL
ODB        ODB123       ODB1        
CDC        CDC123       CDC1
```

Comment: Same file or new file for the updated PASS/FAIL fields? If same file: Will the script be executed another time with PASS/FAIL field already present? And what did you try yourself so far?

Comment: Happy if it is overwritten or appended to the same file.

I tried to put those values into a different file, It worked. I used the below script to do so.

Comment: ` #!/bin/sh

. ~/.ODBenv
cat test.txt | grep '^#' > test1.txt
cat test.txt | grep -v '^#' | awk 'NF'|while read i;do
user_name=`echo $i|awk {'print $1'}`
password=`echo $i|awk {'print $2'}`
TNS_NAME=`echo $i|awk {'print $3'}`
echo "exit" | ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -S  ${user_name}/${password}@${TNS_NAME} |grep -E 'ORA|SP2' > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo -e "${user_name}\t      ${password}\t   ${TNS_NAME}\t   PASS">>test1.txt
else
   echo -e "${user_name}\t      ${password}\t   ${TNS_NAME}\t   FAIL">>test1.txt
fi
done `

Comment: I want it to overwrite the original file with PASS/FAIL values.

Comment: Better put your script in the question, so it can be formatted (preceed each line of the script with 4 spaces) and clarify the problems you had: Were all variables set correctly? Did the database connection succeed? was the file written other than intended?

Comment: I did it in my original Question and yes the database connection succeeded and I am able to write PASS/FAIL contents into a new file. Any idea how to write in the original file as mentioned in the main question/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's just about the editing in place. I prefer `sed -i` for this:

```
tail -n+2 test.txt|while read -r line ; do
  user_name=`echo "$line"|cut -d\  -f 1`
  password=`echo $line|cut -d\  -f 2`
  TNS_NAME=`echo $line|cut -d\  -f 3`
  echo "exit" | ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -S ${user_name}/${password}@${TNS_NAME} |grep -E 'ORA|SP2' > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    result=PASS
  else
    result=FAIL
  fi
  sed -i -E "/$line/s/\t*FAIL|\t*PASS|$/$result/" test.txt
done
```

So, for the given `$line` I remove any trailing `PASS` or `FAIL` with it's tab and replace it by the `$result`. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Philippos

I tried executing your script, but it didnt make any changes in the `test.txt`. Any suggestions here?

And my taught is like initially there wont be any PASS or FAIL in the `test.txt` file. We need to add append PASS or FAIL to the last column of each and every line based on the result.

Comment: No, the `|$` branch works if there is no `PASS` or `FAIL`. I did test it with and without. If it doesn't work with them, they are probably not separated by a tab, so we could use `\s*` instead of `\t`, but I can't understand why it should fail for the first run. Maybe try the `sed` without the script first to know where the problem is.